# How to avoid $.ajaxPrefilter() for http error code 500, 404 but not for 401?

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-status-code-401

I am trying to intercept ajax response for handling the failure of ajax(HTTP error code 401,404 or 500 etc).
I studied that we can do that by using $.ajaxPrefilter(). So I tried, and got success. Here is my code,

```
//the ajax call
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    url: "getPrevActivityLogs",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        'startDate': startDate,
        'finishDate': endDate
    }),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
//todo the codes for successfully ajax response
    }, error: function (data, status) {
        showToastr('Unexpected Server Exception ' + data["message"] + " " + status, 'Activity Load', 'error');
    }
});
```

now the code for intercepting ajax

```
$.ajaxSetup(
    {
       normalizeForStatusCodes: true
    }
);
```

Below the code for ajaxPrefilter:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(
    function( options, localOptions, jqXHR ){
        if (options.normalizeForStatusCodes){
            normalizeAJAXRequestForStatusCodes( jqXHR );// the function where we can play with the success and the failure of ajax call
        }
    }
);
```

the function where we decide what to do when there is an error in ajax

```
function normalizeAJAXRequestForStatusCodes( jqXHR ){
    var normalizedRequest = $.Deferred();
    jqXHR.then(
        normalizedRequest.resolve,
        function (jqXHR ) {
            var msg;
            if (jqXHR.status == 401){
                if($("#login-flow-modal").data('bs.modal') != undefined){ // checks if modal opened 
                    msg = getLoginErrorMessage(jqXHR.responseText);
                }else{
                    msg = ''; // initialise to remove previous error messages
                }
                normalizedRequest.rejectWith(
                    this,
                    [
                        loadLoginFlowModal(msg),
                        "error",
                        jqXHR
                    ]
                )

            }else {
                normalizedRequest.rejectWith(
                    this,
                    [
                        $.parseJSON( jqXHR.responseText ),
                        "success",
                        jqXHR
                    ]
                );
            }
        }
    )
    jqXHR = normalizedRequest.promise( jqXHR );
    jqXHR.success = jqXHR.done;
    jqXHR.error = jqXHR.fail;
 }
}
```

Now these code works just fine. I can able to intercept the ajax for error 401.

My requirement is, I want to intercept only 401 error code. Rest each error codes (say 500, 404 etc.) should be redirected to the original ajax call for the custom handling.